# Why does position absolute work this way with particles.js in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, position, particles.js

I'm trying to understand why position absolute works the way it does in this scenario on elements.

I know that an element with position absolute is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element. In this case, it would be the body element.

If that's the case, why doesn't about.js overlap with the navigation element then (its static!)? Why is it overlapping particles.js (which is what I was trying to achieve).

Now if you put the div with id particles.js on top of the div with class about, then about overlaps with the portfolio section. Can someone explain this?

Here is a sample of my CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img[alt="Profile Picture"] {
  width: 40%;
}
/* why do this work idk */
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.about {
  position: absolute; 
  border: 10px pink solid;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
#particles-js {
  background: rgb(29, 114, 243);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the about section from overlapping the particles section, you want to remove the `position: absolute` rule from `.about`.  This rule is taking `.about` out of the flow block positioned elements and making it overlap.

Also, the navigation element is not being overlapped by the `.about` section.  The navigation elements color is transparent and making it appear this way.  Try adding `background-color: white` rule to the navigation element.